# Como conseguir meter las coordenadas de todos los joints de un body en un Array?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Bueno, estoy intentando programar en C#, soy un novato y utilizando el código de bodybasics de Microsoft, con la ultima versión de Kinect y visual studio 2013. Estoy intentando guardar todas las coordenadas en un array de los 25 joints que saca la cámara Kinect, pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo puesto que son 3 coordenadas xyz. La idea es que se almacenen constantemente para poder ver luego como cambian e interpretar que se ha realizado un movimiento. Alguien tiene alguna idea o podría echarme un cable por favor.

Este es mi código:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Radius of drawn hand circles: Radio de círculos de mano dibujados

    /// </summary>
    private const double HandSize = 30;

    /// <summary>
    /// Thickness of drawn joint lines: Espesor de las líneas de tracción
    /// </summary>
    private const double JointThickness = 4;

    /// <summary>
    /// Thickness of clip edge rectangles:Espesor de los rectángulos del borde del clip

    /// </summary>
    private const double ClipBoundsThickness = 10;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constant for clamping Z values of camera space points from being negative:Constante para fijar los valores Z de los puntos de espacio de cámara de ser negativo
    /// </summary>
    private const float InferredZPositionClamp = 0.1f;

    /// <summary>
    /// Brush used for drawing hands that are currently tracked as closed: Pincel utilizado para dibujar manos que actualmente se siguen como cerradas
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Brush handClosedBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 0, 0));

    /// <summary>
    /// Brush used for drawing hands that are currently tracked as opened: Pincel utilizado para dibujar manos que actualmente se siguen como abiertas
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Brush handOpenBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 255, 0));

    /// <summary>
    /// Brush used for drawing hands that are currently tracked as in lasso (pointer) position:Pincel utilizado para dibujar las manos que se rastrean actualmente como en la posición del lazo (puntero)
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Brush handLassoBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 0, 0, 255));

    /// <summary>
    /// Brush used for drawing joints that are currently tracked: Cepillo utilizado para el dibujo de las articulaciones que se siguen actualmente
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Brush trackedJointBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 68, 192, 68));

    /// <summary>
    /// Brush used for drawing joints that are currently inferred:Pincel utilizado para el dibujo de las articulaciones que actualmente se infiere 
    /// </summary>        
    private readonly Brush inferredJointBrush = Brushes.Yellow;

    /// <summary>
    /// Pen used for drawing bones that are currently inferred
    /// </summary>        
    private readonly Pen inferredBonePen = new Pen(Brushes.Gray, 1);

    /// <summary>
    /// Drawing group for body rendering output: Grupo de dibujo para la salida de la representación corporal

    /// </summary>
    private DrawingGroup drawingGroup;

    /// <summary>
    /// Drawing image that we will display
    /// </summary>
    private DrawingImage imageSource;

    /// <summary>
    /// Active Kinect sensor
    /// </summary>
    private KinectSensor kinectSensor = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Coordinate mapper to map one type of point to another: Mapeador de coordenadas para asignar un tipo de punto a otro

    /// </summary>
    private CoordinateMapper coordinateMapper = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Reader for body frames
    /// </summary>
    private BodyFrameReader bodyFrameReader = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Array for the bodies: Array para los cuerpos
    /// </summary>
    private Body[] bodies = null;


    /// <summary>
    /// definition of bones
    /// </summary>
    private List<Tuple<JointType, JointType>> bones;

    //Dani
    // public List<>

    //Declaracion de una matriz bidimensional
   public float [,] MatrizCoordBodyGlobales= new float[2,2];
    //float[][,][,] ArraydeMatrices;
   //Array rectangular dentro de otro array
   public float[][,] ArraydeMatrices = new float[10][,];
   public int i =0;
   public int j = 0;
   // Me da error este tipo de arrays, MIRAR ESTA PARTE, TENEMOS QUE CONSEGUIR METER LA MATRIZ EN UN HUECO DE UN ARRAY



    /// <summary>
    /// Width of display (depth space)
    /// </summary>
    private int displayWidth;

    /// <summary>
    /// Height of display (depth space)
    /// </summary>
    private int displayHeight;

    /// <summary>
    /// List of colors for each body tracked
    /// </summary>
    private List<Pen> bodyColors;

    /// <summary>
    /// Current status text to display
    /// </summary>
    private string statusText = null;

    //Hecho por Dani
    //private WriteableBitmap colorBitmap = null;
   // private ColorFrameReader colorFrameReader = null;


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainWindow class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainWindow()
    {

        // one sensor is currently supported
        this.kinectSensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();

        // get the coordinate mapper
        this.coordinateMapper = this.kinectSensor.CoordinateMapper;

        // get the depth (display) extents
       //Dani
        FrameDescription frameDescription = this.kinectSensor.DepthFrameSource.FrameDescription;


        // get size of joint space : Obtener el tamaño del espacio de articulación

        this.displayWidth = frameDescription.Width;
        this.displayHeight = frameDescription.Height;


        // open the reader for the body frames : Abra el lector para los marcos del cuerpo

       this.bodyFrameReader = this.kinectSensor.BodyFrameSource.OpenReader();

        // a bone defined as a line between two joints: Un hueso definido como una línea entre dos 
        this.bones = new List<Tuple<JointType, JointType>>();

        // Torso : Añade las distintas lineas de union entre dos partes de una zona concreta del cuerpo, se trata de dibujar el Esqueleto del cuerpo
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.Head, JointType.Neck));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.Neck, JointType.SpineShoulder));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.SpineShoulder, JointType.SpineMid));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.SpineMid, JointType.SpineBase));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.SpineShoulder, JointType.ShoulderRight));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.SpineShoulder, JointType.ShoulderLeft));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.SpineBase, JointType.HipRight));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.SpineBase, JointType.HipLeft));


        // Right Arm
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.ShoulderRight, JointType.ElbowRight));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.ElbowRight, JointType.WristRight));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.WristRight, JointType.HandRight));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.HandRight, JointType.HandTipRight));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.WristRight, JointType.ThumbRight));

        // Left Arm
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.ShoulderLeft, JointType.ElbowLeft));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.ElbowLeft, JointType.WristLeft));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.WristLeft, JointType.HandLeft));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.HandLeft, JointType.HandTipLeft));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.WristLeft, JointType.ThumbLeft));

        // Right Leg
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.HipRight, JointType.KneeRight));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.KneeRight, JointType.AnkleRight));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.AnkleRight, JointType.FootRight));

        // Left Leg
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.HipLeft, JointType.KneeLeft));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.KneeLeft, JointType.AnkleLeft));
        this.bones.Add(new Tuple<JointType, JointType>(JointType.AnkleLeft, JointType.FootLeft));

        // populate body colors, one for each BodyIndex
        this.bodyColors = new List<Pen>();

        this.bodyColors.Add(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 6));
        this.bodyColors.Add(new Pen(Brushes.Orange, 6));
        this.bodyColors.Add(new Pen(Brushes.Green, 6));
        this.bodyColors.Add(new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 6));
        this.bodyColors.Add(new Pen(Brushes.Indigo, 6));
        this.bodyColors.Add(new Pen(Brushes.Violet, 6));


        // set IsAvailableChanged event notifier: En caso de algun cambio, refrescar los datos de marco
        this.kinectSensor.IsAvailableChanged += this.Sensor_IsAvailableChanged;

        // open the sensor
        this.kinectSensor.Open();

        // set the status text
        this.StatusText = this.kinectSensor.IsAvailable ? Properties.Resources.RunningStatusText
                                                        : Properties.Resources.NoSensorStatusText;

        // Create the drawing group we'll use for drawing : Crear un grupo de dibujo
        this.drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();

        // Create an image source that we can use in our image control :Crear una fuente de imagen que podamos usar en nuestro control de imagen
        this.imageSource = new DrawingImage(this.drawingGroup);

        // use the window object as the view model in this simple example
        this.DataContext = this;


            // initialize the components (controls) of the window
            this.InitializeComponent();


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// INotifyPropertyChangedPropertyChanged event to allow window controls to bind to changeable data: Evento para permitir que los controles de ventana se enlacen a datos cambiables
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the bitmap to display
    /// </summary>
    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            return this.imageSource;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the current status text to display
    /// </summary>
    public string StatusText
    {
        get
        {
            return this.statusText;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.statusText != value) 
            {
                this.statusText = value;

                // notify any bound elements that the text has changed
                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StatusText"));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute start up tasks :Ejecutar tareas de inicio
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.bodyFrameReader != null)
        {
            this.bodyFrameReader.FrameArrived += this.Reader_FrameArrived;


        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute shutdown tasks
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
    private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.bodyFrameReader != null)
        {
            // BodyFrameReader is IDisposable
            this.bodyFrameReader.Dispose();
            this.bodyFrameReader = null;
        }

        if (this.kinectSensor != null)
        {
            this.kinectSensor.Close();
            this.kinectSensor = null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the body frame data arriving from the sensor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
  private void Reader_FrameArrived(object sender, BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool dataReceived = false;

        using (BodyFrame bodyFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
        {
            if (bodyFrame != null)
            {
                if (this.bodies == null)
                {
                    this.bodies = new Body[bodyFrame.BodyCount];
                }

                // The first time GetAndRefreshBodyData is called, Kinect will allocate each Body in the array.
                // As long as those body objects are not disposed and not set to null in the array,
                // those body objects will be re-used.
                bodyFrame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(this.bodies);
                dataReceived = true;
            }
        }


        if (dataReceived)
        {
            using (DrawingContext dc = this.drawingGroup.Open())
            {

                // Draw a transparent background to set the render size: Se trata de realizar un fondo , en este caso negro
              dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0.0, 0.0, this.displayWidth, this.displayHeight));


                int penIndex = 0;
                foreach (Body body in this.bodies)
                {
                    Pen drawPen = this.bodyColors[penIndex++];
                    // Dani ICloneable



                    if (body.IsTracked)
                    {
                        this.DrawClippedEdges(body, dc);

                        IReadOnlyDictionary<JointType, Joint> joints = body.Joints;
                        // Console.WriteLine("HandRight" + JointType.HandRight);

                        // convert the joint points to depth (display) space
                        Dictionary<JointType, Point> jointPoints = new Dictionary<JointType, Point>();

                        foreach (JointType jointType in joints.Keys)
                        {
                            // sometimes the depth(Z) of an inferred joint may show as negative
                            // clamp down to 0.1f to prevent coordinatemapper from returning (-Infinity, -Infinity)
                            CameraSpacePoint position = joints[jointType].Position;
                            if (position.Z < 0)
                            {
                                position.Z = InferredZPositionClamp;
                            }

                            DepthSpacePoint depthSpacePoint = this.coordinateMapper.MapCameraPointToDepthSpace(position);
                            jointPoints[jointType] = new Point(depthSpacePoint.X, depthSpacePoint.Y);
                        }

                        this.DrawBody(joints, jointPoints, dc, drawPen);

                        this.DrawHand(body.HandLeftState, jointPoints[JointType.HandLeft], dc);
                        this.DrawHand(body.HandRightState, jointPoints[JointType.HandRight], dc);

                        //SE TRATA DE SACAR LOS PUNTOS X E Y DE LA MANO DERECHA
                        // Distancias sacadas en metros

                        //Mano Derecha
                        VariablesGlobales.HandRightX = body.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.X;
                        VariablesGlobales.HandRightY = body.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Y;
                        VariablesGlobales.HandRightZ = body.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Z;
                        //ManoIzquierda
                        VariablesGlobales.HandLeftX = body.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.X;
                        VariablesGlobales.HandLeftY = body.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Y;
                        VariablesGlobales.HandLeftZ = body.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Z;


                        //Matriz Rectangular multidimensional
                       // float[,] MatrizCoordBodyGlobales = { { body.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.X, body.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Y },
                       // { body.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.X, body.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Y }, 
                        //{ body.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.X, body.Joints[JointType.Head].Position.Y },
                        //{ body.Joints[JointType.SpineMid].Position.X, body.Joints[JointType.SpineMid].Position.Y }};
                        MatrizCoordBodyGlobales[0, 0] = VariablesGlobales.HandRightX;
                        MatrizCoordBodyGlobales[0, 1] = VariablesGlobales.HandRightY;
                        MatrizCoordBodyGlobales[1, 0] = VariablesGlobales.HandLeftX;
                        MatrizCoordBodyGlobales[1, 1] = VariablesGlobales.HandLeftY;

                        // ArraydeMatrices[0] = MatrizCoordBodyGlobales;
                        for (j = 0; j <= 200;j++)
                        {
                            if(j== 200 )
                            {
                            ArraydeMatrices[i] = MatrizCoordBodyGlobales;
                            j = 0;
                            i++;
                            }
                        }



                        // Probar sacar ese punto de coordenada y almacenarlo en una variable.
                        // Se depura , metiendo ventanas-resultados, aqui se pone el punto de parada para depurar


                        // mirar tambien como guardar essos parametros en archivos


                    }
                }

                // prevent drawing outside of our render area: Evitar el dibujo fuera de nuestro área de de devolucion
                this.drawingGroup.ClipGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, this.displayWidth, this.displayHeight));
            }
        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a body
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="joints">joints to draw</param>
    /// <param name="jointPoints">translated positions of joints to draw</param>
    /// <param name="drawingContext">drawing context to draw to</param>
    /// <param name="drawingPen">specifies color to draw a specific body</param>
    private void DrawBody(IReadOnlyDictionary<JointType, Joint> joints, IDictionary<JointType, Point> jointPoints, DrawingContext drawingContext, Pen drawingPen)
    {
        // Draw the bones
        foreach (var bone in this.bones)
        {
            this.DrawBone(joints, jointPoints, bone.Item1, bone.Item2, drawingContext, drawingPen);

        }

        // Draw the joints: Dibujar las articulaciones
        foreach (JointType jointType in joints.Keys)
        {
            Brush drawBrush = null;

            TrackingState trackingState = joints[jointType].TrackingState;

            if (trackingState == TrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                drawBrush = this.trackedJointBrush;
            }
            else if (trackingState == TrackingState.Inferred)
            {
                drawBrush = this.inferredJointBrush;
            }

            if (drawBrush != null)
            {
                drawingContext.DrawEllipse(drawBrush, null, jointPoints[jointType], JointThickness, JointThickness);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws one bone of a body (joint to joint)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="joints">joints to draw</param>
    /// <param name="jointPoints">translated positions of joints to draw</param>
    /// <param name="jointType0">first joint of bone to draw</param>
    /// <param name="jointType1">second joint of bone to draw</param>
    /// <param name="drawingContext">drawing context to draw to</param>
    /// /// <param name="drawingPen">specifies color to draw a specific bone</param>
    private void DrawBone(IReadOnlyDictionary<JointType, Joint> joints, IDictionary<JointType, Point> jointPoints, JointType jointType0, JointType jointType1, DrawingContext drawingContext, Pen drawingPen)
    {
        Joint joint0 = joints[jointType0];
        Joint joint1 = joints[jointType1];

        // If we can't find either of these joints, exit
        if (joint0.TrackingState == TrackingState.NotTracked || joint1.TrackingState == TrackingState.NotTracked)
        {
            return;
        }

        // We assume all drawn bones are inferred unless BOTH joints are tracked
        Pen drawPen = this.inferredBonePen;
        if ((joint0.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracked) && (joint1.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracked))
        {
            drawPen = drawingPen;
        }

        drawingContext.DrawLine(drawPen, jointPoints[jointType0], jointPoints[jointType1]);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws a hand symbol if the hand is tracked: red circle = closed, green circle = opened; blue circle = lasso ( lazo)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handState">state of the hand</param>
    /// <param name="handPosition">position of the hand</param>
    /// <param name="drawingContext">drawing context to draw to</param>
    private void DrawHand(HandState handState, Point handPosition, DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        switch (handState)
        {
            case HandState.Closed:
                drawingContext.DrawEllipse(this.handClosedBrush, null, handPosition, HandSize, HandSize);
                break;


            case HandState.Open:
                drawingContext.DrawEllipse(this.handOpenBrush, null, handPosition, HandSize, HandSize);
                break;

            case HandState.Lasso:
                drawingContext.DrawEllipse(this.handLassoBrush, null, handPosition, HandSize, HandSize);
                break;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws indicators to show which edges are clipping body data
    /// Dibuja indicadores para mostrar qué bordes están recortando los datos del cuerpo
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="body">body to draw clipping information for</param>
    /// <param name="drawingContext">drawing context to draw to</param>
    private void DrawClippedEdges(Body body, DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        FrameEdges clippedEdges = body.ClippedEdges;

        if (clippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Bottom))
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Red, null, new Rect(0, this.displayHeight - ClipBoundsThickness, this.displayWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));
        }

        if (clippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Top))
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Red, null, new Rect(0, 0, this.displayWidth, ClipBoundsThickness));
        }

        if (clippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Left))
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Red, null, new Rect(0, 0, ClipBoundsThickness, this.displayHeight));
        }

        if (clippedEdges.HasFlag(FrameEdges.Right))
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Red, null, new Rect(this.displayWidth - ClipBoundsThickness, 0, ClipBoundsThickness, this.displayHeight));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the event which the sensor becomes unavailable (E.g. paused, closed, unplugged).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
    private void Sensor_IsAvailableChanged(object sender, IsAvailableChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // on failure, set the status text
        this.StatusText = this.kinectSensor.IsAvailable ? Properties.Resources.RunningStatusText
                                                        : Properties.Resources.SensorNotAvailableStatusText;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: StackOverflow en español es por algo lo de español. modifica tu pregunta al castellano por favor

Comment: Ya lo he cambiado. :)

Comment: A los que votaron para cerrar, ya pueden retirar sus votos de cierre.

Comment: No estaria entendiendo el problema. que te impide crear una clase coordenadas y una coleccion?

Comment: Puede que no me haya explicado bien, el problema reside ala hora  de hacer una clonación de la clase interna Body del Kinect para luego poder modificar mi clase (donde implementare lo del array de coordenadas) porque no se me ocurre otra forma de como crear un array almacenando los 25 joints con sus 3 coordenadas respectivamente, se que es posible pero no veo la manera de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3 handRight = new Vector3();
handRight.X = skeleton.Joints[JointID.HandRight].Position.X; 
handRight.Y = skeleton.Joints[JointID.HandRight].Position.Y; 
handRight.Z = skeleton.Joints[JointID.HandRight].Position.Z;

Vector3 head = new Vector3(); 
head.X = skeleton.Joints[JointID.Head].Position.X; 
head.Y = skeleton.Joints[JointID.Head].Position.Y; 
head.Z = skeleton.Joints[JointID.Head].Position.Z;
```

Puedes obtenerlas directamente utilizando la propiedad Joints y almacenandola en variables ya sean Float o Vector (xyz), saludos.

Una disculpa, no se aplicar formatos, es mi primera respuesta.